# Generative adversarial networks application to reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, gan

Can generative adversarial networks be applied to reinforcement learning?

Like imitation learning or inverse reinforcement learning?

Comment: Adversarial approach has already been used in RL. Look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03476) paper for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can generative adversarial networks be applied to reinforcement learning?

*Yes.*

How the training of a GAN is formulated [has been shown](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03852.pdf) as applicable to inverse RL. We know a GAN has a Discriminator $D$ whose objective is to distiguish between the real data and fake data created by the Generator. The Generator $G$, on the other hand, learns to generate samples that look as similar as possible to the real data.

#### How this applies to Imitation and Inverse RL

The GAN Discriminator learns by reducing the Binary Cross-Entropy Loss(BCE) between the real and fake data:

$log(D_{\phi}(x))+log(1−D_{\phi}(G(z)))$, where $x$ is a real sample, and $G(z)$ is a fake output from the Generator.

Similar to this, Inverse and Imitation RL use expert demonstrations to ultimately train a policy. These demonstrations can be regarded as the *real* data while the transitions the learning policy $\pi_{\theta}$ collects when running in the environment, as the *fake* data. We utilize the Discriminator in this case to maximize the probability of correctly classifying a transition $\tau$ as being from expert demonstrations $*p$ or a sample from the learned policy $\pi_{\theta}$. We can express this as:

[image]

*The transitions $\tau$ are drawn from the expert distribution $\tau \sim *p$ in the first part of the equation, and drawn from the policy samples $\tau \sim \pi_{\theta}$ in the second part.* In other words, we try to maximize the likelihood of a transition coming from the expert distribution $*p$ while minimizing that from the policy distribution $\pi_{\theta}$.

This improves the objective of the Discriminator which is to minimize BCE loss between expert demos and generated samples.

#### How does this meet the RL objective?

The objective of RL is to maximize the cumulative future reward $r(s_t, a_t)$. Since imitation and inverse RL do not utilize an inbuilt reward function, we utilize the Discriminator objective to replace the policy optimization objective.

$r_{\phi}(s_t, a_t) = log(D_{\sim *p}(s, a)) − log(1 − D_{\sim \pi_{\theta}} (s, a))$

So we turn the Discriminator minimization objective into maximization.
The learned policy is then updated using $r_{\phi}$ to make it's samples harder to distinguish from the expert demos - much like a Generator in a GAN:

$\sum \nabla_{\theta} \pi_{\theta} r_{\phi}(s_t, a_t)$

We can summarize all this in an image:
[image: GAN-GCL process]

#### And where is the difference between Imitation and Inverse RL here?

Quick definitions:

- **Imitation Learning**: Recovers a policy from the expert demonstrations by mimicking the expert behaviour.
- **Inverse RL**: Infers the expert's intention by recovering a reward function from the demonstrations. This means that when the expert makes mistakes or shows sub-optimal behaviour, the policy won't overfit to such behaviour/mistakes but instead focus on the expert's intention.

The difference is in how we formulate the Discriminator. For imitation learning, the Discriminator $D$ will be a standard binary neural net classifier that can't optimize for the expert's intention - it just learns to mimic what the expert does.
In inverse RL though, $D$ will take the form of a learnable reward function $f_{\phi}(\tau)$, expressed as:

$D_{\phi} = \frac{exp f_{\phi}(\tau)}{exp f_{\phi}(\tau) + \pi_{\theta}(a|s)}$

Updating the Discriminator $D_{\phi}$ updates the reward function $f_{\phi}$.

**In other areas**, GANs have also been used for Transfer Learning in RL through [Domain Adaptation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejhoffman/domainadapt/) during Sim-to-Real transfer. [Here's an example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.07857.pdf). This uses a complete GAN architecture with both a Discriminator and a Generator.